# Django inline formset add another and remove

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to build this following link feature in django,
http://demo.smarttutorials.net/jquery-autocomplete/

Here by choosing serial_no and the rest of the fields name and author should be auto populate. Auto populate works for first inline formset and able to save it but when I add another inline formset auto populate is not working plus I'm unable to delete it or save it.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    serial_no = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomerOrder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer  =  models.ForeignKey(CustomerOrder)
    serial_no = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(max_length = 100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from bookapp.models import CustomerOrder


class CustomerOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomerOrder
        exclude = ('customer',)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from bookapp.models import *
from bookapp.forms import CustomerOrderForm
import json
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory


def home(request):
    context =  RequestContext(request)
    OrderFormSet =   inlineformset_factory(CustomerOrder, Order  ,extra=1, exclude=('customer',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        customerorderform = CustomerOrderForm(request.POST)
        orderformset = OrderFormSet(request.POST)
        if customerorderform.is_valid() and orderformset.is_valid():
            a = customerorderform.save()
            orderformset.save(commit=False)
            orderformset.instance = a
            orderformset.save()
            return HttpResponse('Added')
    else:
        customerorderform = CustomerOrderForm()
        orderformset = OrderFormSet()
        for orderform in orderformset:
            orderform.fields['serial_no'].widget.attrs = {'id' : 'sno', 'onkeydown':"myFunction()"}
            orderform.fields['name'].widget.attrs = {'id' : 'bname'}
            orderform.fields['author'].widget.attrs = {'id' : 'bauthor'}

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args = {'customerorderform':customerorderform, 'orderformset':orderformset}
    return render_to_response('home.html',args,context)

def fetch_serial_nos(request):
    serial_nos = map(lambda x: str(x.serial_no), Book.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(content = json.dumps({'serial_nos': serial_nos}), content_type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")

def get_entry_corresponds_to_serial_no(request):
    serial_no = request.GET['serial_no']
    try: 
        entry = Book.objects.get(serial_no=int(serial_no))
        data = {'name': entry.name, 'author': entry.author}
    except (ObjectDoesNotExist, ValueError):
        data = {'name': '', 'author': ''}
    return HttpResponse(content = json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

home.html

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.formset.js"></script>


<p>Enter S.NO</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".inline.{{ orderformset.prefix }}").formset({
            prefix: "{{ orderformset.prefix }}",
        })
    })
</script>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Orders</h1>
        <form action="/"  method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div>
                <legend>Customer</legend>
                {{customerorderform}}
            </div>
           <fieldset>
                <legend>Order</legend>
                {{ orderformset.management_form }}
                {{ orderformset.non_form_errors }}
                {% for form in orderformset %}
                    {{ form.id }}
                    <div class="inline {{ orderformset.prefix }}">
                        {{form}}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Add order" class="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/serial_nos/',        
        success: function (response) {
        serial_nos = response['serial_nos'];
        $( "#sno" ).autocomplete({
            source: serial_nos
         });
        },        
    });   
    });
function myFunction(){ 
    var sno = document.getElementById("sno").value;
    console.log(sno)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + sno;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/entry/',
        data : {
            serial_no : sno,
        },        
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('success') 
            bname.value = response['name'];
            bauthor.value = response['author'];

        },        
    });
  }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code.

1. You set the same ID for multiple HTML elements which is totally incorrect. The meaning of an ID is to be unique. When you search for element by ID it will return only one (the first matched element).
2. You initialize autocmplete only on initial page loading. Instead you need to initialize it for every new row created by formset javascript. This can be done by using `added` callback configured in `formset` options. Look for details at the documentation https://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/wiki/Usage#Formset_options

Also I have some suggestions for your code to be more ideologically correct.

1. Don't use `from module import *`
2. Reorder your imports (firs put imports from standard library, second put imports from framework and at the end put imorts from your project)
3. Do not set in python attributes like `onkeydown`, `onclick` and so on. Use Javascrirpt for that. (This is probably more important then first two)